# PCA method after StandardScaler produces poor results

Tags: machine-learning

I tried to classification problem for fun with the scikit-learn library. I got 10000x10 dimension data, and I found very weird phenomenon (for me).

```
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
ss = StandardScaler()
X = pca.fit_transform(X) # explained_variance_ratio_ = 0.8
X = ss.fit_transform(X)
```

in this case, i got a wonderfull explained_variance_ratio_ almost 99%. but when I apply scaling first, suddely PCA's performence is dropped drastically and explained_variance_ratio decreased to 20%.

```
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
ss = StandardScaler()
X = ss.fit_transform(X)
X = pca.fit_transform(X) # explained_variance_ratio_ = 0.2
```

What makes this difference? Standard Scaler is just rescaling process, so I suppose no information loss. Can I apply the PCA before for visualizing conveniency? Or I must select Standardization for mathematical insurance?

Comment: If all of your variables are in the same unit it may not be a good idea to rescale. Is it the case ?

Comment: What are the means of "variables are in the same unit"? My dataset has 10 variable for each observation and total observation number is 10000. some variable has {0,1}, other's are integer varying within 1-10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you have two features **A** and **B** that  measure distance and both are in metres. Feature **A** has a greater range of numbers in it (suppose, 1 - 1000) as compared to a Feature **B** , which has a range( suppose, 1-10). 
Then, the feature **A** will capture greater **variance** in the data as compared to **B**, and hence it is not a good idea to scale the features in this case .
 But if , the features are having two different units,(say, kg and metre), then it will be wise to scale the features.

P.S: **PCA** preserves those components along which there is max. **variance**.

Comment: So PCA result before scaling is biased to some enormous big number, I suppose? then 0.2 is the real result with pca. My dataset has different unit for all values, so standard scaling is inevitable. Perhaps I must forgot the glorious graph for better performance. Thanks for help.